# Can blender export files for games, probably for mods?

Tags: modeling, export

I'm thinking of creating mods for games. I want to know whether or not I can use blender for exporting game models.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), then use the [**edit link**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/134527/edit) below your question and add information to make your question more specific and less generic.

Answer (score -1):

its done using the fbx file export from blender generally...you'll have to look at what the game engine your looking at wants for setting up stuff within the file in blender, like collision objects names(ends in _ucx for unreal etc.. since blender exports fbx files i know they will go into unreal 4 at least.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/addons/io_fbx.html

for unity
https://answers.unity.com/questions/439807/blender-to-unity-which-export-format-is-best.html

for unreal 4
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Content/Types/StaticMeshes/HowTo/Importing
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-us/Engine/Content/Types/SkeletalMeshes
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Content/FBX
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Engine/Content/QuickStart